# How to show all node child, childs and more deep using XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, exist-db

This is DTD file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!ELEMENT akweny (akwen+)>
<!ELEMENT akwen (nazwa, typ, powierzchnia, akweny?)>
<!ELEMENT nazwa (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT typ (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT powierzchnia (#PCDATA)>
```

And for example XML (its valid ofc)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE akweny SYSTEM "akweny.dtd">
<akweny>
    <akwen>
        <nazwa>Atlantycki</nazwa>
        <typ>ocean</typ>
        <powierzchnia>106450</powierzchnia>
        <akweny>
            <akwen>
                <nazwa>Północne</nazwa>
                <typ>morze</typ>
                <powierzchnia>750</powierzchnia>
            </akwen>
            <akwen>
                <nazwa>Batyckie</nazwa>
                <typ>morze</typ>
                <powierzchnia>386</powierzchnia>
                <akweny>
                    <akwen>
                        <nazwa>Botnicka</nazwa>
                        <typ>zatoka</typ>
                        <powierzchnia>117</powierzchnia>
                    </akwen>
                </akweny>
            </akwen>
        </akweny>
    </akwen>
    <akwen>
        <nazwa>Spokojny</nazwa>
        <typ>ocean</typ>
        <powierzchnia>179700</powierzchnia>
    </akwen>
</akweny>
```

And ofcorse here is simple Xpath

```
    let $nodes := doc('/db/Dane/akweny.xml')//akweny[ancestor::akwen/nazwa="Atlantycki"]
        for $x in $nodes/*
        let $nazwa := $x/nazwa/text()
..
            return
```

But if i change nazwa="Atlantycki" to nazwa="Północne" it nothing shows. It's correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*if i change nazwa="Atlantycki" to nazwa="Północne" it nothing shows. It's correct?*". Yes, that's an expected behavior.

basically, this XPath query :

```
//akweny[ancestor::akwen/nazwa="Atlantycki"]
```

will search for `<akweny>` element having ancnestor :

`<akwen>` element having child :

`<nazwa>Atlantycki</nazwa>`

So if you change `nazwa="Atlantycki"` to `nazwa="Północne"` the query will return nothing. Because the only `<akwen>` element met the query **is not a parent of any** `<akweny>` element :

```
<akwen>
    <nazwa>Północne</nazwa>
    <typ>morze</typ>
    <powierzchnia>750</powierzchnia>
</akwen>
```

In other words **no** `<akweny>` **element met the query**.

Comment: Thx so much for that information. But someone can help me faind evrythink below nazwa="Atlantycki"? Plz

Comment: it is not clear which elements you want precisely? how about this : `//akweny/akwen[/nazwa='Atlantycki']/akweny/akwen`. If that isn't what you're looking for, I'd suggest to edit the question, post all XML elements you want the XPath to return.

Comment: Ok evrythink is ok ;) THX!